# Select data from specific row of grouped and joined table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have two tables, customers and orders which are inner joined. A customer can have several orders associated with them. In my selection, I then group by customers.id. I need to select the most recent order of each customer, but also the amount of money spent in that order. Currently, I can select the most recent order_date but do not know how to select the amount in the same row as the order_date.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    email, 
    MAX(order_date) AS recent_order, 
    amount -- this needs to select amount associated with recent_order
FROM customers
JOIN orders
    ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.id;
```

The query selects the most recent date, but does not select the amount associated with the most recent order_date.

Table declarations:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(100),
    last_name VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date DATE,
    amount DECIMAL(8,2),
    customer_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT c.*, o.*  -- or whatever columns you want
FROM customers c JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.id = o.customer_id
WHERE o.order_date = (SELECT max(o2.order_date)
                      FROM orders o2
                      WHERE o2.customer_id = o.customer_id
                     );
```

For performance, you want an index on `orders(customer_id, order_date)`.

Comment: Why do you recommend this?

Comment: Thank you, this works! However, is there any way to do this using a group by, since from my understanding having the subquery would reduce performance

Comment: @Cirrus86 . . . Actually, `group by` is often going to be slower.  Add the recommended index, and you probably can't get a faster query.

Comment: @RMac . . . Because this should have the fastest performance across most databases, including MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    email, 
    MAX(order_date) AS recent_order, 
    (SELECT amount FROM orders WHERE order_date = MAX(order_date) AND customers.id = orders.customer_id) as amount
FROM customers
JOIN orders
    ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.id;
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    email, 
    order_date AS recent_order, 
    amount AS recent_order_amount
FROM customers
JOIN orders
    ON customers.id = orders.customer_id

GROUP BY customers.id
ORDER BY orders.order_date DESC;
```

Comment: The first option throws a 'ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function'. The second option throws a 'ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY customers.id' at line 21'. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: the second should be work now.
Problem at first is use of MAX and GROUP BY

Comment: Using order by after group by just orders the grouped rows rather than the values within the groups

Comment: The first one throws error "Aggregate calls are not allowed here"

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1
    t1.first_name, 
    t1.last_name, 
    t1.email, 
    t2.order_date,
    t2.amount
FROM customers t1
JOIN orders t2
    ON t1.id = t2.customer_id
ORDER BY
    t2.order_date
```

Add a `GROUP BY t1.id` if the intent is to return all rows with the most recent order_date. Omit this if every order is resented by a single row in `orders`. Note this will not sum the amounts. You will have to do that in code or else use a different query. Also note that performance of this query will be affected by configuration of indexes. This query may not be performant if order_date is not part of an index and the table contains a large data set.

Comment: The issue is that the GROUP BY clause cannot come after ORDER BY, at least in MySQL. Putting the GROUP BY before the ORDER BY would just order the groups

Comment: That's why you keep the TOP 1 and ORDER BY parts of the query...